# Javascript-generated embedded Vimeo players fail after a while

Tags: javascript, vimeo

We have a website that loops through a playlist of Vimeo IDs, embedding an iFrame player until the video is done playing, destroying said I frame and starting over with the next video id. This seemingly works fine but stops working after an arbitrary number of idle hours. Our tests have been made in Chrome 59 on OSX. Here is a screenshot of the kind of errors that end up in our console.

[As this is my first post, here's the link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7hcC.png)

We're not sure what could be causing this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's the Javascript responsible for creating/destroying iframes. Also, the project is using AngularJS but I don't think it's relevant. :

```
var iframe_wrap = document.getElementById('player-wrap');
var iframe = document.getElementById('player');
var player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
});

function onFinish() {
    // Remove current iframe
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
    player = null;

    // Video increment
    if((ctrl.currentVideo + 1) < ctrl.currentPlaylist.length) {
        ctrl.currentVideo += 1;
    }
    else {
        ctrl.currentVideo = 0;
    }

    // Create new iframe
    var newPlayer = '<iframe id="player" 
src="'+ctrl.currentPlaylist[ctrl.currentVideo].urlVimeo+'" 
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    if(ctrl.currentPlaylist[ctrl.currentVideo].contentType =='scenario'){
        iframe_wrap.innerHTML = newPlayer;
    }

    iframe = document.getElementById('player');
    player = $f(iframe);
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Certainly! I edited the post!